# Can't access public page feed even if I'm admin of the page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created an app with the sole purpose to read `/feed` endpoint of public a page. Page is created by me and app is in development mode, so according to [Facebook API Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS), I'm allowed to get data from this endpoint using App Access Token:

> While you are testing your app and before you submit it for review, your app can only access content on a Page for which the following is true: The person who holds the admin role for the Page also holds an admin, developer, or tester role on the app.

But when I make the request to feed with app access token, I get the following error:

> (#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

I'm developing a server side app I can't use an user access token. What I'm missing here?

Comment: With an app access token, you are not impersonating any particular user or page - so there is no one here that could have given you access to a specific page they manage, so this _is_ “public” access. You need to use a user or a page access token.

Comment: @04FS, I don't quite get it. How can I test then my app? Do I need 2 auth. flows one which requires user action to receive user token just for testing and another flow for live mode where user is not needed?

Comment: You don’t necessarily need to implement the full login flow, you can f.e. also get a token from Graph API Explorer, and then copy&paste it into your code for testing.

Comment: @04FS, I already did that and it's working, but I can't hardcode the token somewhere in properties of application just for testing ... Is my understanding correct that once approved by Facebook, my app will be able to make requests with app access token?

Comment: I guess, at least that’s what the documentation still states. (But if you are not creating an app that has the general purpose of reading stuff from public pages, but want to use this for your own page only [not sure what exactly you are planning?], I would not bet on Facebook approving this in review to begin with.)

Comment: You should be able to make request using your user access token, not the app access token, provided the user is group's admin. Probably you will be able to use app token after getting Facebook approval, but before that user access token should be fine.

Comment: I understood that, the client just won't accept an app with hardcoded token, even only during testing. What I'm supposed to say? "Trust me, I'm engineer"?